# Large link border with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

In this line of my text when I had to use a `cases` environment within the text I got a large link border around 1. How to make it regular like any others references? Below a MWE of my code:

[image: Large box around 1]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{linkcolor = {0 .8 1}}
\usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
        left = 2cm,
        right = 2cm
    }
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axioma}
\begin{document}
    \begin{ax}\label{ax:1}
        Dados dois triângulos \( ABC \) e \( EFG \), se \( AB\equiv EF \), \( AC\equiv EG \) e \( \hat{A}\equiv\hat{E} \), então \( ABC\equiv EFG \).
    \end{ax}    

    \begin{proof}
        Seja \( ABC \) e \( EFG \) dois triângulos de correspondência \( ABC\leftrightarrow EFG \). Assim, por hipótese tem-se \( AB\equiv EF \) e por construção tem-se \( AD\equiv EF \). Pelo axioma \ref{ax:1}: \( \begin{cases}
        AC\equiv EF \\
        \hat{E}\equiv C\hat{A}D \\
        AD\equiv EF
        \end{cases} \Rightarrow \triangle ACD \equiv \triangle EFG \).
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's an odd way of presenting the discussion; to have regular-spaced lines and then one line that is super-wide. Why not set the content in display math `\[`...`\]`?

Comment: When I compile your code with `xelatex`, I do not get this large box. How do you compile your code?

Comment: Please tell us whether you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile this code snippet.

Comment: I compiled it with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX and I got the same with both, @Mico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to use inline math mode for the entire proof, both because super-tall lines are ugly and because the use of inline math doesn't do a good job of visually highlighting what the main logical step is.

I'm afraid I'm not fluent in Portuguese, but assuming I understood the material correctly, I think it's better to use `\angle` than `\hat` to denote, well, angles.

For the following screenshot, the code was compiled under pdfLaTeX. Results with either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX are virtually the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brasilian'?

\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifluatex
   \usepackage{unicode-math,lualatex-math}
\else\ifxetex
   \usepackage{unicode-math}
\else
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi\fi

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor = {0 .8 1}}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ax}{Axioma}

\begin{document}
\begin{ax}\label{ax:1}
Dados dois triângulos $ABC$ e $EFG$, se $AB\equiv EF$, $AC\equiv EG$ 
e $\angle{A}\equiv\angle{E}$, então $ABC\equiv EFG$.
\end{ax}    

\noindent\dots

\begin{proof}
Seja $ABC$ e $EFG$ dois triângulos de correspondência $ABC\leftrightarrow EFG$. 
\dots\ Assim, por hipótese tem-se $AB\equiv EF$ e por construção tem-se 
$AD\equiv EF$. 
\[
\text{Pelo \cref{ax:1}: }
\begin{cases}
    AC\equiv EF \\
    \angle E\equiv C\angle AD \\
    AD\equiv EF
\end{cases} 
\quad \Rightarrow \triangle ACD \equiv \triangle EFG.
\qedhere % take care to place the QED symbol
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, kindest now I have finished all my votes :-) See later your email. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The linkborder adapts to the surrounding box. As you have a large cases in the current line, you get a large link box. You can avoid it by putting an additional \mbox around the ref:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{linkcolor = {0 .8 1}}
\begin{document}

\section{xxx}\label{test}

\rule{2mm}{1cm} high: \ref{test}, short: \mbox{\ref{test}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]